# Onclick event on search bar suggestions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have added a search bar with suggestion elements. On click of search bar all the elements is displayed but onclick event is not working on these list suggestion elements.

Have added click event to these suggestions which is stored in li .I want some actions to be performed onclick of these elements

```js
$(document).on("click", ".search.search-list", function(e) {
  console.log('clicked')
})
```

```css
.search {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.search input {
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 12px 0 25px;
  /* background: white url("https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") 8px 6px no-repeat; */
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
  border-radius: 13px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}

.search input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #66b1ee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}

.search input:focus + .results { display: block }

.search .results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search .results li { display: block }

.search .results li:first-child { margin-top: -1px }

.search .results li:first-child:before, .search .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -11px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:hover:before, .search .results li:first-child:hover:after { display: none }

.search .results li:last-child { margin-bottom: -1px }

.search .results a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search .results a span { font-weight: 200 }

.search .results a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  /* background: url("https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat; */
}

.search .results a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
  background-color: #338cdf;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf); */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input { line-height: 26px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <div class="modal fade" id="search-bar" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog search-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content search-modal">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <section class="main">
                        <form class="search">
                            <input type="text" class="search-input" name="q" placeholder="Search..." />
                            <ul class="results" >
                                <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #1<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li> 
                                 <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #2<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
                                <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #3<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
                                <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                   </section>
                  </div> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your click handler should not be on `.search.search-list`, but on `.search .search-list`

Comment: @Aioros Tried it..Still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make two changes. I'll explain what I did.

1. The reason why the click event on `search-list` was not working is because you have defined it in js as `.search.search-list`. There should be a space between them, like `.search .search-list`, as @Aioros suggested.
2. You have displayed the dropdown using CSS `:focus`, like when the cursor is inside `search` input, the dropdown should show. Now when the user clicks on one of the items from the dropdown, the focus shifts away from the search input field, thus making the dropdown invisible again. I have used a small jQuery solution to display the dropdown when the user clicks on search field.

```js
$(".search-input").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".results").css({
    "display": "block"
  });
  console.log("HEY");
})


$(".search .search-list").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log('clicked')
})
```

```css
.search {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.search input {
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 12px 0 25px;
  /* background: white url("https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") 8px 6px no-repeat; */
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
  border-radius: 13px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}

.search input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #66b1ee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}


/*.search input:focus + .results { display: block }*/

.search .results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search .results li {
  display: block
}

.search .results li:first-child {
  margin-top: -1px
}

.search .results li:first-child:before,
.search .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -11px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:hover:before,
.search .results li:first-child:hover:after {
  display: none
}

.search .results li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -1px
}

.search .results a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search .results a span {
  font-weight: 200
}

.search .results a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  /* background: url("https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat; */
}

.search .results a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
  background-color: #338cdf;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf); */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input {
  line-height: 26px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="modal fade" id="search-bar" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog search-modal">
    <div class="modal-content search-modal">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <section class="main">
          <form class="search">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" name="q" placeholder="Search..." />
            <ul class="results">
              <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #1<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
              <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #2<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
              <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #3<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
              <li class="search-list"><a href="">Search Result #4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </form>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me the changes made please